# Errors are ignored by the microsoft bot framework

Tags: python, botframework

I am just starting to modify the echobot provided by Microsoft

```
class EchoBot(ActivityHandler):
  
  async def on_message_activity(self, turn_context: TurnContext):    
    return await turn_context.send_activity(MessageFactory.text(f"Echo: {message_text}"))
```

for some reason any errors in my code are ignored, as in the bot hides any error messages and simply fails to return from `await ADAPTER.process_activity(...`

for example if I modify the code above to

```
class EchoBot(ActivityHandler):
  
  async def on_message_activity(self, turn_context: TurnContext):  
    throw("ERROR!")
    return await turn_context.send_activity(MessageFactory.text(f"Echo: {message_text}"))
```

it shows no sign of failure in the console.  Do they write their errors somewhere else?  This makes it impossible to debug any issues whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Found a problem.  Their sample includes this

```
# Catch-all for errors.
async def on_error(context: TurnContext, error: Exception):
  # This check writes out errors to console log .vs. app insights.
  # NOTE: In production environment, you should consider logging this to Azure
  #       application insights.
  logger.error(f"\n [on_turn_error] unhandled error: {error}") , file=sys.stderr)
```

removing **file=sys.stderr** sends the output to the console.